# Ruby including files

Tags: ruby, class, path, include

I have a Ruby app that runs on a server with no web interface.  It is run using the command `line`(ruby path/to/file.rb).

I have classes in different files that I want to be accessible. The files are located in the "app/classes" directory.

I put this in the application.rb file:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/classes"]
```

and I get an uninitialized constant error.

I can put in "require_relitive 'somefile'" but I would rather not have to do this for every class that is used.  How do I create an autoload path and where should it be located at?

Answer (score 1):

Use `require_all`

See https://github.com/jarmo/require_all

It basically allows you to write this:

```
require 'require_all'
require_all 'app/classes'
```

And all ruby files in app/classes will be loaded.

Comment: I was able to get this in eviroment.rb to work: AUTOLOAD_PATHS = [
  Dir["#{PCP_ROOT}/app/classes/*.rb"],
  Dir["#{PCP_ROOT}/lib/*.rb"]
]  But I have a custom_logger.rb in lib directory that doesn't seem to be loading.  Any ideas?